# bash how to redirect output from a function to /dev/null

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I have a script with some functions (`~/func/functions.sh`)
and I have the other script (`~/scripts/example.sh`)

Code: functions.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 function NameofFunction()
 {
  # do something...
  echo -e "\e[31m[ ERROR ]\e[39m more text..." 1>&2
  }
```

Code: example.sh (work well)

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/func/functions.sh
function functioninExample()
{
#do something...
NameofFunction ${VAR1} ${VAR2}

}

functioninExample 2>/dev/null
```

Code: example.sh (doesn't work)

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/func/functions.sh
function functioninExample()
{
#do something...
NameofFunction ${VAR1} ${VAR2} 2>/dev/null

}

functioninExample
```

How can I redirect the echo from my function without editing the function?

```
NameofFunction ${VAR1} ${VAR2} 2>/dev/null
```

doesn't work.

How can I redirect the echo from my function without redirecting the functioninExample function?

Comment: Could you please change `${VAR1}, ${VAR2}` to some real strings and show us what is your function printing exactly?

Comment: example for ${VAR1} 50000 and for ${VAR2} 2000
i start some pearl scripts and check the arguments of my script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your function is printing to `stdout` not `stderr`, try

```
NameofFunction ${VAR1} ${VAR2} >/dev/null
```

or redirect both `stderr` *and* `stdout`:

```
NameofFunction ${VAR1} ${VAR2} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Note it's good style to print errors to `stderr`, so instead of my answer above you should better change your function, like this:

```
echo -e "\e[31m[ ERROR ]\e[39m more text..." 1>&2
```

Comment: Hi, this dosnt work, i tested it before

Comment: @FaxMax Using the exact code you posted it worked for me, please make a minimal example that actually doesn't work.

Comment: @Random832 you are right, i testet it with 2 new files, i updated my question. thanks!

Comment: @FaxMax Both of your examples still work for me. What does it do, and are you actually running your examples to confirm that they don't work? If whatever you're _really_ doing isn't working, maybe the problem is in something you cut out for the examples.